# How to find the diff of hours between two dates?

Tags: java, spring

have two LocalDateTime and I want to find the diff of hours between them and save them in an Integer.
I was doing something like this

```
      app.setTimeLeftToEnable(app.getDisableAt().getHour() - localDateTimeNow.getHour());
```

but after testing this is wrong, I am getting the result wrong somehow,
can anyone help me, please?

Comment: [`LocalDateTime#until(Temporal,TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). [`Duration#between(Temporal,Temporal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)).

Comment: I found the best way to do this is with ChronoUnit.

`long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(fromDate, toDate);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(fromDate, toDate);` do you thing this is a good way to do it

Comment: Check here : https://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DateDifferent.shtml

Comment: I just need to see the hours not the min

Comment: If below answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Joda-Time Library you can do like this :

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
Period p = new Period(startTime, endTime);
long hours = p.getHours();
```

> Edit

With Java8

```
Instant strt,end;
Duration duration = Duration.between(strt, end);
long hrs = duration.toHours();
```

Comment: I need only the hours

Comment: Don't use Joda. It is essentially a dead project and users are asked to migrate to Java 8 (Date & Time API).